# Deleting documents in Firestore not updating onSnapshot

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am fetching a list of items from firestore in react native.

If an item document is updated, my list refreshes as expected through onSnapshot. But if the document is deleted, my list does not refresh.

Is there a way for me to catch deleted documents?

```
this.unsubscribe = firebase.firestore().collection('bigItems').doc(id)
                  .collection('littleItems').onSnapshot(this.getItems)

   getItems = (querySnapshot) => {
     const items = [];

    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      firebase.firestore().collection('events').doc(doc.id).get()
        .then(item => {
            const { id } = item.data();
            items.push({
              id: item.id
            });
            this.setState({
              items: items,
              loading: false,
           });
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          return err;
        });
    })
  }
```

Comment: Did you ever get this solved? Having the same issue here, where I've made a chat - and if it's deleted on the server side, while the user is subscribed to the conversation, I'd like to detect that, instead of getting permission errors.

Comment: I eventually redesigned my database so that documentsA contain a list of other documentsB they subscribe to. 

I snapshot those documentsB with the "array-contains" operator. 

When an object is deleted, I fire a cloud function which removes the listing from documentsA, and this is captured by the snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

Try if the following approach works for you:

```
const dataRef = firebase.firestore()
            .collection('bigItems').doc(id)
            .collection('littleItems').onSnapshot(res => {

            // Listen to change type here
            res.docChanges().forEach(change => {

            const docName=change.doc.id;
            const docData=change.doc.data();

            // Refer to any field in the document like:
            // E.g. : data.name, data.text etc.
            // i.e. (whatever fields you used for the document)

            if (change.type === "added") {
                // Append to screen
            }
            if (change.type === "removed") {
                // Now, Manually remove from UI
                // Data from state before snapshot is still here,
                // use some reference in data to remove from screen.
            }
        });
    });
```